# Unable to link shared libraries not under the system library directories on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I created a shared library, libsslab_core.so.1.0.0 using gcc with proper options. I am pretty sure that the shared library works because I already linked it to another source code (I explicitly tells a compiler, gcc, the location of the library using -l option of the compiler).

After testing the library works, I tried to integrate the library into my Linux machine. I went to the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ and added a file, sslab.conf. In the file I just typed the absolute path of the library, /opt/lib/sslab. Next, I executed ldconfig as a root to update the cache file of ldconfig. And I checked if the system finds the newly added library by typing ldconfig -p | grep libsslab. My Linux machine found the library, so I thought everything is finished.

However, when I try to compile a source code using the library, it gives me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsslab_core
```

When I move the library to /usr/local/lib, update the content of sslab.conf, and execute ldconfig as a root. I can use the shared library without any problems.

Do you have any ideas about the problem that I've come across on Ubuntu 12.04?

For your information, I refer to a document in TLDP to generate my own shared library. Here is the link: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/

Comment: ldconfig only affects the runtime linker (ld.so), not the one that comes with the compiler. You still have to use -L for the latter.

Comment: When gcc compiles a source code with a shared library, does it find the library in directories in order, which are registered by ldconfig? As I wrote, when my shared library is under the system library directories such as /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib, or /lib, I don't need to specify the location of the library when compiling. If you are right, what does it mean that adding a library location to the ld.so.conf? Can you give me more detailed information?

Comment: man ldconfig says: "configure dynamic linker **run-time** bindings". Pretty clear IMHO.

Comment: Your first opinion is not correct. For example, you don't need to specify the location of a pthread library when your compiler uses it. What you need to do is just add this: -lpthread. In addition, I don't need to use -L option to specify the location of the library. However, I have to use -l option to specify the name of the library to use functions in any libraries. In this case, my shared library is under the default linux library directories such as /lib or /usr/local/lib.

Comment: Let me clarify my question again: "Why can a gcc compiler not find the location of added libraries when they are not under the default linux library directories even when ldconfig knows their locations?

Comment: Because `gcc` is not `ldconfig`. `gcc` (actually `ld`) knows where the libraries are from its own configuration files and/or hardwired information. It has no idea about `ldconfig`. It just so happens that by default the library search path usually includes `/usr/lib`, `/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` (and maybe also some other directories like `/lib64`). So most libraries installed on your system like `libpthread` can be found by default without `-L`. You can print the search path with `ld -v --verbose | grep  SEARCH_DIR`. You use `-L` to add other directories to that list.